# perl one-liner + add condition before edit file

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I have this line in my configuration file

```
     MY_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

I want to change by perl one-liner line , the word **PASSWORD** to other word as - **MY_SECRET_PASS**

so I write this perl liner syntax ( this perl is inside my bash script )

```
      perl -i -pe "s/PASSWORD/MY_SECRET_PASS/"   file
```

I want also to add condition to my perl one-liner syntax that will check if **PASSWORD**
defined after **MY_PASSWORD=**

so only if it ture , then perl will replace the **PASSWORD** , with **MY_SECRET_PASS**

if not perl  will exit without do anything

example:

```
  more file


  MY_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

after running the perl line file should be like this:

```
      MY_PASSWORD=MY_SECRET_PASS
```

but as I said perl line must to check first the existing of the word PASSWORD after MY_PASSWORD= ,

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please give examples

Comment: Presumably by "liner line" you mean "one-liner".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will match `MY_PASSWORD=PASSWORD`, but replace only `PASSWORD` part,

```
perl -i -pe 's/MY_PASSWORD=\K PASSWORD/MY_SECRET_PASS/x' file
```

`\K` is a zero-width [positive look behind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3c%3dpattern%29-%5cK), and `/x` tells regex to ignore white-spaces which may improve regex readability.

UPDATE:

for very old versions of perl (`5.8.x` and older)

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=MY_PASSWORD=)PASSWORD/MY_SECRET_PASS/' file
```