# perl one liner + remove password from script by perl one liner line

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, ksh

I use a perl one liner in my bash script ,

in order to remove the password from the script ( because security issues , it’s not bad solution when we want to remove password from scripts )

the problem is when I run the bash script , the perl one line  delete his line ,

the word after:  **export PASSORD=**

please advice what need to update in the perl one liner line in order to ignore the removing of the word in the perl line ?

remark - the export ... line not in the begining og the line

perl one liner line from my script:

```
     perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD=).*//' /tmp/script.bash
```

the script before we run it

```
   more /tmp/script.bash

   #!/bin/bash


    export LOGIN=root
    export PASSORD=JH&*(@%VTVTB


    /var/cti/download_password.ksh $PASSORD $LOGIN

       perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD=).*//' /tmp/script.bash
```

the script after we run it

```
  more /tmp/script.bash

   #!/bin/bash


    export LOGIN=root
     export PASSORD=


     /var/cti/download_password.ksh $PASSORD $LOGIN

     perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD=
```

Comment: `perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD=` what about remaining part?

Comment: the perl line delete it line itself ( this is the problem )

Comment: Didnt you already ask this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064853/perl-one-liner-add-condition-before-edit-file

Comment: this is diff quastion , because this is diff problem

Comment: " it’s not bad solution when we want to remove password from scripts" - yes, it is - because putting plaintext passwords into script was bad to begin with.

Comment: @Bushmills the password will deleted in the begining , immedditaly after we run the script , so whats bad on that

Comment: have you thought about why, say, password file with passwords to log into a system, doesn't contain plaintext passwords? While that file isn't even run at all ...

Comment: this solution isnt 100% but its works , any way this isnt what I ask ,

Comment: I had to read the other question to get context of what's being asked here. You do realize that the `perl` line does not have to be in the script that you are going to modify, right? Then again, if you are going to add this line in, you may as well just remove the password directly.

Comment: Still, it was an answer, namely "don't remove password only when script starts to execute, but remove them completely"

Comment: the perl must be in the scipt , I dont have other chioce

Comment: @Bushmills please be focus on my quastion , the perl line must be in my script because some limitations

Comment: OK , so please give me other solution how to delete password from script , when password must ne inside the script because I dont have other choice???

Comment: other solution chould be like read the password from other file , but still need to delete this file , so on both scenarios that the same

Comment: I think the below solutions should work, but I am curious why you don't just `unlink` the file. It seems like you are generating it on the fly.

Comment: yes its also good option , but I think my solution is also very good

Comment: I tested it 1000 times and evry time the password deleted , second password are always in the begining of the script so no chance that script fail in the start ....

Comment: Are you creating this script to launch another command without the argument/password appearing in the process list?

Comment: I guess the question is why do you care about the state of this file after you run it. If it's so important why is it in /tmp?

Comment: I care because password should not apears on files/script inspite they under /tmp -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match space by `[ ]` to avoid matching particular line,

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export[ ]PASSORD=).*//' /tmp/script.bash
```

Comment: yes its work like a charm -:)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the one-liner so it can only have whitespace in front of the match:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\s*export PASSORD=\K.*//' /tmp/script.bash
```

This uses the `\K` flag which requires Perl 5.10.

Alternatively, put one of the letters in a character class (`[]`) so the regex no longer matches its literal self:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSOR[D]=).*//' /tmp/script.bash
```